# Custom Max aggregate on a Date column in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, max, aggregate, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to perform a custom max aggregate on a date column in a kendo grid and display it using the ClientFooterTemplate at the bottom of the column. I want to calculate the max aggregate only when all dates under the date column have values.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<InstallerWrapper>().Name(@"InstallerTable")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Model(m => m.Id(o => o.InstallerId))
                                    .Read(read => read
                                        .Action("GetInstaller", "DataProvider", new { orderId = Model.OrderId })
                                        .Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                                    .Aggregates(aggregates =>
                                    {
                                        aggregates.Add(o => o.SurveyReceivedDate).Max();
                                    })   
                                    .PageSize(20)

        )

    .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.InstallerId).Title("Installer")
                           .ClientTemplate("#=VendorName#")
                           .Filterable(false).Width(225)
                           .ClientFooterTemplate("All")
                           .Sortable(false);    

                columns.Bound(o => o.SurveyReceivedDate).Title("Survey Received")
.HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" })
.Filterable(false)
.ClientTemplate("#=SurveyReceivedDate#")
                   .ClientFooterTemplate("#=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(max),'MM/dd/yyyy')#")
                   .Sortable(false);

            })

        .Selectable()
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Pageable(p => p.Refresh(true)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function in the ClientFooterTemplate for the column to get this.

```
 columns.Bound(o => o.SurveyReceivedDate).Title("Survey Received").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal" }).Filterable(false)
               .ClientTemplate("#=SurveyReceivedDate#")
               .ClientFooterTemplate("#if (getMaxDateText()){#   #} else{# #=kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(max),'MM/dd/yyyy')# #} #")
               .FooterHtmlAttributes(new { style =" color: red "})
               .Sortable(false);
```

Javascript Function:

```
<script>
    function getMaxDateText() {
        var surveyReceivedArray = [];
        var data = $("#InstallerTable").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            surveyReceivedArray.push(data[i].SurveyReceivedDate);

        }

        var isAtLeastOneNull = surveyReceivedArray.some(function (o) { return o === null; });

        if (isAtLeastOneNull) {
            return true;
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```